# Action while Button is Pressed

Tags: ios

I have a button I would like to perform an action as long as it is pressed down. When it is let go, the action should stop. For example, my button is to show a picture upon button press until it is let go. How is something like this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start your action on the `touchDownInside` and stop it on the `touchUpInside` actions - you can hook them up in IB.